# SELECT Only Records With Duplicate (Column A || Column B) But Different (Column C) Values

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I apologize for the confusing title, I can't figure out the proper wording for this question. Instead, I'll just give you the background info and the goal:

This is in a table where a person may or may not have multiple rows of data, and those rows may contain the same value for the `activity_id`, or may not. Each row has an auto-incremented ID. The people do not have a unique identifier attached to their names, so we can only use first_name/last_name to identify a person.

I need to be able to find the people that have multiple rows in this table, but only the ones who have multiple rows that contain more than one different `activity_id`.

Here's a sample of the data we're looking through:

```
unique_id | first_name    |   last_name    |    activity_id
---------------------------------------------------------------
 1        | ted           | stevens        | 544
 2        | ted           | stevens        | 544
 3        | ted           | stevens        | 545
 4        | ted           | stevens        | 546
 5        | rachel        | jameson        | 633
 6        | jennifer      | tyler          | 644
 7        | jennifer      | tyler          | 655
 8        | jennifer      | tyler          | 655
 9        | jack          | fillion        | 544
 10       | mallory       | taylor         | 633
 11       | mallory       | taylor         | 633
```

From that small sample, here are the records I would want returned:

```
unique_id | first_name    |   last_name    |    activity_id
---------------------------------------------------------------
 dontcare | ted           | stevens        | 544
 dontcare | jennifer      | tyler          | 655
```

Note that which value of `unique_id` gets returned is irrelvant, as long as it's one of the `unique_id`s belonging to that person, and as long as only one record is returned for that person.

Can anyone figure out how to write a query like this? **I don't care what version of SQL you use, I can probably translate it into Oracle if it's somehow different.**

Comment: Please leave a comment if you feel the need to down-vote this question. I'd like to find out what it is that you think I've done poorly so I can address the issue. I found it very difficult to put this into writing, but I did the best that I can.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the question. And it helped me. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id)
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) > 0;
```

Comment: Wow, I avoided trying this because I assumed COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) would do a DISTINCT check on ALL results, so if both Ted and Mallory are in the same activities, only one of them would get returned. It appears I'm wrong, your query seems to work. Can you explain why?

Comment: Well.. I guess it's because HAVING modifies the group, and not the full record-set. I didn't know that... I feel like a dunce now.

Comment: @BumbleShrimp HAVING has more wierd features in MySQL look at this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81c0a/25 it can also be used without GROUP BY.. note Oracle en Postgresql will break on this syntax

Answer (score 2):

I'll build through the logic with you.  First, lets find all people that have more than one entry:

Unique list of name + activity ID:

```
select first_name, last_name,activity_id, count(1)
from yourtable
group by first_name, last_name,activity_id
```

Now we'll turn that into a subquery and look for users with more than 1 activity_ID

```
Select first_name, last_name
from 
    (select first_name, last_name,activity_id, count(1)
    from yourtable
    group by first_name, last_name,activity_id) a
group by  first_name, last_name
having count(1) > 1
```

Should work as that...I didn't return an activity_id, adding max(activity_id) to the select statement will grab the highest one.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that which value of unique_id gets returned is irrelvant, as long as it's one of the unique_ids belonging to that person, and as long as only one record is returned for that person.**

These querys should do the trick. there is no need for distinct keywords or an subquery to fetch the results BumbleShrimp needs (if BumbleShrimp needed the correct unique_id also an subquery is needed to match the right value)

Below is the most simple query i could think off that should work, but it could be slow on large tables.

```
SELECT 
   first_name
 , last_name 
 , activity_id
FROM 
 person
GROUP BY 
   first_name
 , last_name
 , activity_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Could be slow because explain shows "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort".
Using temporary could trigger an disk based temporary table so we make use off an inner self join to remove the need of an Using temporary.

```
SELECT 
   person1.first_name
 , person1.last_name
 , person1.activity_id
FROM 
 person person1
INNER JOIN
 person person2

ON
 person1.unique_id < person2.unique_id
AND 
 person1.first_name = person2.first_name
AND 
 person1.last_name = person2.last_name
AND 
 person1.activity_id = person2.activity_id

ORDER BY 
    activity_id asc
```

See demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe3ba/29

**Side note the inner join will fail if there are three or more duplicates**
see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ff33/15

New query

```
SELECT 
   first_name
 , last_name 
 , activity_id
FROM 
 person
GROUP BY 
   activity_id
 , last_name
 , first_name
HAVING COUNT(activity_id) >= 2
ORDER BY 
 activity_id asc
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e418/3 fixes the three or more duplicates problem / orders activity_id right and can be used on large tables because there is not need off a temporary table what can slow down the execution

Comment: I can't seem to get either of your queries to return Mallory Taylor's result.  I went ahead and added her into the data set.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0299e/1

Comment: True the querys are correct you are mixing activity_ids between "jack fillion" and "mallory taylor"   this works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81714/1 like it should

Comment: In the example you just linked, Mallory Taylor should **not** get a result returned, because she does not have more than one activity ID assigned to her.  The query needs to only return the names of people who have more than one *different* activity (IE 544 and 545, not 544 and 544). Sorry if I worded my question poorly.

Comment: no problem i totally missed the clue ("But Different (Column C) Values") in the title..

Answer (score 0):

To get only the names, the simplest is:

```
SELECT 
    first_name
  , last_name 
FROM 
    person
GROUP BY 
    first_name
  , last_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) >= 2 ;
```

To get one row for every name, you can use window function (work fine in Oracle):

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        unique_id, first_name, last_name, activity_id
      , COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) OVER (PARTITION BY last_name, first_name)
          AS cnt 
      , MIN(unique_id) OVER (PARTITION BY last_name, first_name)
          AS min_id 
    FROM 
        person
  )
SELECT
    unique_id, first_name, last_name, activity_id
FROM 
    cte
WHERE
    cnt >= 2
  AND
    min_id = unique_id ;
```

Instead of `MIN(unique_id) OVER ...`, you could use `MIN(activity_id) OVER ...` (or `MAX()`) and accordingly `min_id = activity_id`. Or `ROW_NUMBER()` function. Since you need the `COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id)` anyway, let me add this version.

With an index on `(last_name, first_name, activity_id, unique_id)` it should be quite efficient:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        unique_id, first_name, last_name, activity_id
      , COUNT(DISTINCT activity_id) OVER (PARTITION BY last_name, first_name)
          AS cnt 
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY last_name, first_name 
                           ORDER BY activity_id, unique_id)
          AS rown 
    FROM 
        person
  )
SELECT
    unique_id, first_name, last_name, activity_id
FROM 
    cte
WHERE
    cnt >= 2
  AND
    rown = 1 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03646/1)**

Comment: Never used window functions in Oracle. but isn't this slow on large tables i read in the documentation "For each row, a sliding window of rows is defined."  sounds to me this is some kind off correlated subquery. in  MySQL correlated subquerys are really slow but i know Oracle is an more mature database but does Oracle handle this efficient on an large table because ive no idea what the explain plan would look like for the window function query?

Comment: Oracle is much more mature indeed. And correlated subqueries (or even more complex queries) can be efficient with proper indexing.